# Android: Spinner dropdown transperent

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-spinner, android-custom-view

M developing an application in which I am using a spinner. Now I want to transparent the background of dropdown list of the spinner.

[image]

In the above screen i want to transparent the background of A, B, C...

I want to apply a transparent background so that the background lay is visible.
I tried so and applied a transparent image to spinner dropdown in custom adapter and it looks like following :

[image]

I want to remove the white background of dropdown which is the background in following image.

[image]

Comment: you have to implement style/theme to achieve this or you can achieve by having button on which open the custom dialog.

Comment: @smkrn110 can you explain or having any example?

Comment: Have a button instead of spinner, on click event display the dialog (on dialog implement your own custom layout). Create a layout for dialog (with linearlayout and one listview). Create CustomListAdapter extending BaseAdapter. Create another layout (with linearlayout and a textview) and Inflate it using CustomListAdapter on ListView.

Comment: @smkrn110 is there any way to change in spinner itself???

Comment: [see here](http://androidexample.com/Spinner_Basics_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=82&aaid=105)

**dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
                     (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);** this is where you set layout for the dialog appear when you click on spinner.

Answer (score 1):

```
Add this transperency code before your color code ex for 100% :- #FF7c7c7c
Trasparent color codes

100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```

Answer (score 0):

For your concern U can try putting transparent background for same ...

for ex:

```
android:background="#00424242"
```

// #00424242 -- This will represent transparent color

Comment: `#00424242` is not transparent, but `#42FFFFFF` is. The first digits specify alpha.

Answer (score 0):

Your your own text view and apply this text view to your adapter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tv_spinner_entry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="your color"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_all"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
```

Comment: i want to remove white background and gray image i am applying which is transparent.